# Python Subprocess - stderr erases after read

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, popen

I'm using python 2.7 and trying to check if stderr in the first 10 seconds of execution returned any errors, and if not, to continue the process, I'm not waiting for the process to end since it's a loop.

I got this code:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(
            ["python", os.getcwd() + "/start.py", 1hr, 30min, 0, 0],
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        if len(p.stderr.readlines()) is not None:
            print p.stderr.readlines()
            return jsonify(status="failed",
                           error_details=p.stderr.readlines()
                           )
```

The thing is that after reading the length of stderr, stderr clears itself so I cannot check the value and post the message, so the `print p.stderr.readlines()` becomes an empty list.

```
{
  "error_details": [], 
  "status": "failed"
}
```

I don't want to display the output, I just want to run `start.py` and check for errors, if no errors turn up in 10 seconds or so, it means everything went well, and can continue and run the loop started by subprocess in background without checking on it. Can I somehow continue and if somehow the `p` process failed to return an error even after 1 hour or so, to execute a callback? Can I store stderr somehow to reply with the message? Also, how do you suggest I make a counter for that 10 seconds to check if an error popped up? Using `p.pool()` does not return any error code, even if the file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

of course you could store the result of `readlines` so you don't consume the buffer, but your code has a more serious issue.

Using `subprocess.PIPE` for both `stdout` and `stderr` and try to read `stderr` after that can result in a *deadlock*.

Besides, in some cases, the process can silently fail and nothing is written in `stderr`. This isn't the proper way to get return code.

The only (and easier way) to do this is to use `communicate`:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(
            ["python", os.getcwd() + "/start.py", "1hr", "30min", "0", "0"],
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out,err = p.communicate()
rc = p.wait()
if rc: # non-zero return code
        return jsonify(status="failed",
                       error_details=err.decode().splitlines())
```

you get output & error read in 2 separate threads transparently (no deadlock possible), and you test the *return code*. If not zero, then an error has occurred. Split the lines of the decoder error output (python 3) and return your error.

Note that `splitlines()` removes the lines terminations (as opposed to `readlines()` on a stream.

That approach above cannot handle the "wait 10 seconds then test error output" approach. This can:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(
            ["python", os.getcwd() + "/start.py", "1hr", "30min", "0", "0"],
            stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, # don't read stdout, avoids deadlock
            # stdout=devnull, # python 2, where devnull = open(os.devnull, 'w')
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
# now wait 10 seconds
time.sleep(10)
if p.poll() is not None and p.poll() != 0:    
    return jsonify(status="failed",
                   error_details=p.stderr.readlines() # add .decode() for python 3
                   )
```

that above approach wait 10 seconds, then tests if process has ended with error, returns the error / reads error output.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was googling for 2 days with no results. I used the approach in which I'm checking for errors after 10 seconds, and I just had to edit `stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL` to `stdout=devnull` and add `devnull = open(os.devnull, 'w')`.